# How to delete or reset previous values from addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

Lets imagine an event in a calendar, when you click on it, a modal window appears with several buttons. The following code is working, but when I click on different events, the values of previous clicked events are stored and the function FUNC_DELETE_EVENT is called several times with those previous values (I need to call that function ONLY with the last clicked event):

**Javascript**

```
 eventClick:  function(event) {
 document.getElementById("del_event").addEventListener("click",
     function() {
            func_delete_event(event.id); }, false); 
     },
}
```

**Modal**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="del_event" >DELETE</button>
```

**Javascript function called when clicked**

```
function func_delete_event(idevent) {
    *//this is the function called several times with previous event ids*

     // Process to delete the event idevent

}
```

How can I remove previous clicks to call the function **func_delete_event ONLY with the last clicked event**?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

you would use `removeEventHandler` with **exactly the same** arguments as when you `addEventListener`

To do that, make your event handler a locally scoped function

```
eventClick: function (event) {
    var element = document.getElementById("del_event");

    function handler() {
        element.removeEventListener("click", handler, false); // remove this click event handler
        func_delete_event(event.id);
    }

    element.addEventListener("click", handler, false);
},
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! Unfortunately, the modal box doesn't appear when I enter into eventClick

Comment: well, that part of the event handler hasn't changed at all - you get any console errors in your developer tools?

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to copy the bootstrap library, the modal window appears ok, however the problem is still happening, when I call the func_delete_event function, it starts as many times as I clicked in previous events. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your function must have a name and must be global, to be visible in method removeEventListener. 
One way of implementations:

```
var myfunction;

//---------------------------------------
 eventClick:  function(event) {
 document.getElementById("del_event").addEventListener("click",
     myfunction = function() {
            func_delete_event(event.id); }, false); 
     },
}

function func_delete_event(idevent) {

document.getElementById(idevent).removeEventListener("click", myFunction);

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time! Unfortunately, the modal box doesn't appear when I enter into eventClick

Comment: function doesn't have to be global at all

Comment: I'm sorry, I forgot to copy the bootstrap library, the modal window appears ok, however the problem is still happening, when I call the func_delete_event function, it starts as many times as I clicked in previous events. The same happens deleting the function declaration. Thank you